# NextAuth Get Session in API Route fetching with server component in App Router

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm using Next.js with Auth.js, however, this work fine on fetching with client component but while fetching with server component, session is null.

```js
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { authOptions } from "@/utils/authOptions";

export async function GET(req: NextRequest) {
    const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
    try {
        if (!session) throw new Error("Unauthorized")
        return NextResponse.json({success: true}, { status: 200 })
    } catch (error: any) {
        return NextResponse.json({
            success: false,
            error: error.message || "An error occurred",
        }, { status: 400 })
    }

}
```

So I tried put header() on fetch

```js
const getUser = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/example`, {
    headers: headers()
  });
  return res.json();
};
```

However, this is only work on development but it's error on deployment

```
o [Error]: Headers cannot be modified. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/headers
    at Proxy.callable (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:114384)
    at M (/opt/node-bridge/bridge-server-NOEMJORR.js:1:6156)
    at Object.mutateHeaders (/opt/node-bridge/bridge-server-NOEMJORR.js:2:1036)
    at /opt/node-bridge/bridge-server-NOEMJORR.js:1:887
    at /opt/node-bridge/bridge-server-NOEMJORR.js:1:4962
    at _optionalChain (/opt/node-bridge/bridge-server-NOEMJORR.js:1:865)
    at a (/opt/node-bridge/bridge-server-NOEMJORR.js:1:4884)
    at i (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:177566)
    at F (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/638.js:1:39682)
    at /var/task/.next/server/chunks/638.js:1:41831
```

Answer (score 0):

After I spend a day finding a solution, I found out that I need to use

```js
new Headers(headers())
```

instead of using headers()

```js
const getUser = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/example`, {
    headers: new Headers(headers())
  });
  return res.json();
};
```

This worked for me!